# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_XL_API_30 was killed

Tags: android, android-emulator

While trying to run the emulator I'm getting this error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_XL_API_30 was killed

I have updated my Android Studio and everything also deleted old AVD created new one still same error.

[image: error-image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the drive where your emulator is don't have enough space on it. Check for the drive it should be having **7-10 GB** free space.

If that doesn't work Edit your AVD and change `Graphics` option to `Software` as it might be the graphics issue too. Also update the emulator if its available.

Also check for your `ANDROID_HOME` variable. Check if its pointing to the right location. It should be your `SDK` location.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same problem.
I tried several solutions from stackoverflow but it didn't work.
Finally I noticed that this issue occurs from macOS Big Sur 11.3 update.

### Steps to fix the issue:

1. Open `Terminal` and go to the directory `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/`
2. Create an xml file named `entitlements.xml` with `touch` or `cat` commands
3. Add this content to the `entitlements.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

4. Then simply sign the `qemu-system-x86_64` with it:

```sh
codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force qemu-system-x86_64
```

Now simply restart Android Studio and the Android Emulator should work again!

Comment: but mine is windows how can i fix it with same method?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of small amount memory. I did notice that about 7Gb SSD memory needed to launch AVD.
It works for me )